# Dojo: TabContainer - how to place menu button in the header?

Tags: javascript, dojo, tabcontainer

is it possible to place a button in TabContainer header on the left side ?

I want to place it next to First Tab.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to create your own tab controller widget.  The steps would be as follows:

- Create MyTabController that extends `dijit.layout.TabController`
- Create a template for MyTabController that has a place for the button
- Update MyTabController javascript to create the button

You can use your new controller widget in one of two ways.  If it were me, I'd also create my own tab container widget that extends `dijit.layout.TabContainer` and overrides the `_makeController` function to instantiate the new controller.

Alternatively, you could pass in the `_makeController` function when instantiating the TabContianer widget

```
var tc = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
    _makeController: function(srcNode) {
      ...
    }
}, node);
```

You can look at the `dijit.layout.TabContainer` source to see what needs to be done in the `_makeController` function.